# Pandas - Keep largest value comparing to next row

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,3,4,4,2,3,4,5,3,4], columns=['len'])
```

I only want to keep a value if the next row is larger or equal than the current one.

The expected output would be:

```
    len
2   4
4   4
5   4
9   5
11  4
```

However, I tried with:

```
df[(df.len.ge(df.len.shift(-1)))]
```

But it removes the last row. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via `fill_value` parameter in `shift()` method:

```
m=df['len'].ge(df['len'].shift(-1,fill_value=df['len'].iloc[-1]))
#you can also use fill_value=df.loc[len(df)-1,'len']
#Finally:
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

output of above code:

```
    len
2   4
4   4
5   4
9   5
11  4
```

**Note:** If you don't want to use `fill_na` parameter in `shift()` method then you can also use `fillna()` method to achieve the same

Answer (score 2):

I think it works.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,3,4,4,2,3,4,5,3,4], columns=['len'])
>>> df[df >= df.shift(-1, fill_value=0)].dropna()
len
2   4.0
4   4.0
5   4.0
9   5.0
11  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this as well:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,3,4,4,2,3,4,5,3,4], columns=['len'])

df[df.len.ge(df.len.shift(-1).fillna(df["len"].iat[-1]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `diff` to compare rows and then check where it is `<=0` for form the Boolean mask.

Use `True` as the fill_value as you want to also include the last row (which is the only `NaN` with all valid `'len'` values)

```
df[df['len'].diff().le(0).shift(-1, fill_value=True)]

    len
2     4
4     4
5     4
9     5
11    4
```